# django migrations always run twice for unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a django project with some unit tests. When I run the tests, I usually skip migrations, because they take a lot of time. I use the the `keep` argument of the django test runner:

`manage.py test --keep`

This works fine. When I need to run migrations, I use:

`manage.py test --noinput`

This runs migrations as I would expect. However, when I **now** run

`manage.py test --keep`

it runs the migrations for the **second** time as if ignoring the `keep` argument. The third and subsequent commands work again correctly skipping the migrations.
I tested this behavior on two different projects and it is the same. Is it default django behavior? Can it be somehow avoided? I don't need the second migration.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mean `--keepdb`?
I don't see any `--keep` option.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/overview/#preserving-the-test-database

Comment: Neither do I, but it works and it has the same effect. It is perhaps an undocumented variant of `--keepdb`. Maybe someone would be able to say what is the differene between the two.